# Can't find Add-ons -> Languages and many other buttons in my personally built Firefox 44.0.2

Tags: c, windows, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

I'm building latest Firefox 44.0.2 on my Windows machine. I want my built version `completely identical in the looking` with the the one coming from the official installer. By `completely identical in the looking` I mean all the buttons, menus, UI language should be the same.

I followed this guidance: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Simple_Firefox_build/Windows_Firefox_build

My mozconfig file is below:

```
mk_add_options MOZ_MAKE_FLAGS=-j10
mk_add_options MOZ_CO_PROJECT=browser
ac_add_options --enable-crashreporter
ac_add_options --enable-release
ac_add_options --enable-update-channel=release
ac_add_options --enable-update-packaging
ac_add_options --enable-jemalloc
ac_add_options --enable-verify-mar
export BUILD_OFFICIAL=1
export MOZILLA_OFFICIAL=1
export MOZ_OFFICIAL_BRANDING=1
mk_add_options BUILD_OFFICIAL=1
mk_add_options MOZILLA_OFFICIAL=1
mk_add_options MOZ_OFFICIAL_BRANDING=1
ac_add_options --enable-official-branding
ac_add_options --with-branding=other-licenses/branding/firefox
```

But still I found some differences between my version and the official version.

1. The official version is a Chinese edition. But I don't know how to specify the UI language in my building? So the binaries generated are just directly Chinese edition?
2. I found that my built version has no `Add-ons -> Languages` option, which the official software has.
3. Some buttons are missing, shown as the picture below (above is the official Firefox, below is my built Firefox). Their names are `Undo, Easy Screenshot and 打开微信网页版` (which means `open WeiXin web version`). I don't know what these buttons are actually? Add-ons? How can I integrate them into my build? I searched them in the Add-ons page but no luck to locate them. If it's impossible to integrate these buttons in the building process, can I add them manually after the build?

[image]

So how to make my build exactly the same like the official Firefox? Thanks!

Comment: I have not used a chinese version, but I suspect that "easy screenshot" is not part of official mozilla builds. so whatever you got there may not actually be an official build. you should also test against an empty profile. the other part probably related to [localized builds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Creating_a_language_pack)

Comment: @the8472 OK. I found Easy Screenshot and some other plug-ins in Internet. I want to know how to integrate custom plug-ins into the build? Thanks

Comment: Then that's not part of an official build, you can't expect it to be included in the result of a build process. Bundling addons is a separate issue, consult MDN on addon installation options

Comment: @the8472 Is there a way for me to build firefox with some add-ons? Those add-ons are not made by me. And I don't have their source code (I think .xpi is the binary file?). I just want to integrate their binaries into my build. Is it possible?

Comment: I think that may be possible, but I don't know how. It's probably somewhere on the wiki.